# Primary Domain Controller Doesn't Work after adding DC

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012-r2, domain-controller, replication

I have added two `2012 R2` `DC`s (Server `B` and `C`) to an existing domain with one `2008 R2` `DC` (Server `A`). After that I transfered all master roles from `A` to `B` and checked it (`netdom query fsmo`) replication works without errors (`repladmin /replsummary`). I set the IP for `A` and `B` as Preferred and alternative `DNS` as well.

The point is when I disconnect server `A`. The domain does not work properly. I have checked the list of DCs and it said that I have 3 `DC`s and that B is the `PDC`. When I tried to get the list of `DC`s it lists `\\A.domain.com` as the PDC and not `\\B.domain.com`.

Can somebody please help me?

Comment: `tried to get the list of DCs`. What does this mean?

Comment: `when I down the A. the domain does not work properly` - What does that mean?

Comment: I have tried to check that all additional DCs are preent in the network. i have check using nltest /dclist:mydomain and it repleid all original anad additional DCs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem was replication service, DFS must be Run and Auto

Answer (score 0):

There are a few more details needed to understand your problem.
When you say "the domain does not work when i take down server A"
Do you mean that other computers on the network can't login?
Or maybe that you cannot login to the other DCs?

A few things that you need to consider:
If you want to take down the original DC you need to do dcpromo to the old server and this will take him out of the domain the right way, you can't just shut it down.

You need to make sure that all of your network devices\computers\servers... DNS configuration is configured to the new IP addresses of the new DCs.

You need to make sure that the initial replication has ended properly (one thing that will indicate it will be to check both new servers for SYSVOL and NETLOGON shares, if you don't see them on both servers so the initial replication did not finished properly).

Hope it will help you, or at least direct you in the right direction :)

Comment: thanks for ur reply.  I try to test in case that I have lost original DC Server A. I have checked that SYSVOL and NETLOG is not present in repolicate dservers Server B and C despite they told me that replication is terminated without error also regarding domain is not working: it is not possible to join new computer any more

Comment: As i undrestand teh problem might be for DNS that can not resolve other DCs to the original one. but I can ping all DCs by name

Comment: Do you have a FW between the DCs?

Comment: I have FW but they are dowm

Comment: I asked if you have FW between the servers?

Comment: I asked because its important that the proper ports will be open between the DCs.
Are all the servers on the same LAN with no restrictions between them?
Sometimes when FW is involved some of the ports will be closed and some will be opened, in these cases it is possible to have a successful insertion of the new DCs to the domain but actually they will not be able to fully sync and work properly.